# Will Davinci Resolve work on Mac Book Pro 13? (integrated Iris graphics, no dedicated GPU) Did anyone manage to run it? It crashes for me on startup

Tags: davinci-resolve

Can you help me out? Will it be possible to run it on my laptop?

Also, how can I view the crashlog to better diagnose the issue (I'm new to mac, and new to Davinci Resolve).

Answer (score 1):

You can save a copy of the DaVinci Resolve crash logs to your desktop by going to the Help menu and selecting "Create Diagnostic Logs on Desktop".

The [DaVinci Support and Troubleshooting FAQ](https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=90190) has a section on the subject with a few procedures to follow in case the app doesn't start. Search the page for "Logs".

I am running Resolve on a 2020 MacBook Pro 13. It works fine for checking edits on the go but I wouldn't use it as a main editing machine.